# SASS Grunt error

Tags: javascript, ruby, gruntjs

I try to added the Sass task to my grunt process using the grunt-contrib-sass plugin but when i run it he create the css files but this file is empty

This is my Gruntfile.js :

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style:'expanded',
                    trace: true
                },

                files: {
                    'main.css':'sass/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

When i start the command "grunt" i have this :

> Running "watch" task
>  Waiting.....
>  File "sass\app.scss"
>   changed
>  Running "sass:dist"  task 
>  (and nothing)

I have :

- Ruby 2.1.5 [x64-mingw32]
- SASS : 3.4.10
- Grunt : newest version

Thanks !

Comment: Could you post your `sass/app.scss` file?

Comment: @JanickBernet Nothing very advanced, I just put a rule in another : .coco {
    margin: 2px;
    h1 {
        margin: 5px;
    }
}

Comment: Can you tell us your folder structure? I think its something to do with the path "sass/app.scss". See that the file location is correct relative to the gruntfile location.

Comment: I have some trouble to make a line break so here a link for the image of the folder structure : [link](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/692328screenshot214.png) as you can see when i start the command "grunt" the files main.css is created but he just dont compile the instruction from app.scss into main.css

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing this:

watch: {
    css: 
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
    }
}

To this:

watch: {
    css: 
        files: '/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
    }
}

To make sure it watches from the root of the project

Comment: I change to : watch: { css: files: '/**/*.scss', tasks: ['sass'] } } but it does not work. Do you think the problem come from Ruby and not Grunt ? Actually when i start a watch with Ruby command it work. Maybe Grunt have not access to Ruby's gems ? I really dont know.